# Group by with a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that we cannot use a subquery in the group by clause. Trying to understand how this works.

if have 2 tables dept and dept_code and im looking at the aggregate of salary by dept code.

Say i choose to use a subquery instead of a join.

```
    create table #dept (id int,name varchar(10),salary int)
    create table #dept_codes (id int,name varchar(10),code varchar(10))

    insert into #dept values (1,'HR',100)
    insert into #dept values (2,'IT',500)
    insert into #dept values (3,'HR',1500)
    insert into #dept values (4,'HR',200)
    insert into #dept values (5,'MAR',1200)

    insert into #dept_codes values (1,'HR','XX')
    insert into #dept_codes values (2,'IT','XXY')
    insert into #dept_codes values (3,'MAR','XXYZ')
```

The query I would give is:

```
     select (select code from #dept_Codes b where b.name = a.name) as code
         ,sum(salary) as salary
     from #dept a
     group by a.name
```

Output is:

```
     code salary
     XX     1800
     XXY     500
     XXYZ    1200
```

I am trying to understand how this works. If I have 2 join conditions in the subquery, do I give both columns in the group by clause?

And is the query true for all cases with a subquery in select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to specify both columns in you `group by`, yes. All columns you reference in the outer table (`#dept a` in your example) must either be aggregate functions like `sum()`, or included in the `group by`.

This extends to columns from the outer table in the correlated subquery as well. If you were to add, say, `and a.id = b.id` to your subquery, it will throw an error

`Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
 Column '#dept.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Great thank you. Does the order in which we specify in the group by make a difference here? considering they are used only for the psuedo-column?

Comment: I don't think so, but to be honest, I haven't tested it. Functionally the order doesn't matter in the slightest. However I can *potentially* see a case for the order mattering for performance if you've got a backing index . If so you might test to see if following or not following the index column order makes any difference in performance.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Xedni pointed out you need both columns in the GROUP BY.  I would suggest using a JOIN instead, if only for readability.

```
 SELECT a.name,code,SUM(salary) AS salary
 FROM #dept a
 INNER JOIN #dept_codes b ON a.name=b.name
 GROUP BY a.name,code
```

Or, if you don't want name in the results (you still need both columns in the GROUP BY):

```
 SELECT code,SUM(salary) AS salary
 FROM #dept a
 INNER JOIN #dept_codes b ON a.name=b.name
 GROUP BY a.name,code
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a "group by", you don't have to select the columns in the "group by". 
Therefore you could have just as easily written.

```
 select sum(salary) as salary
 from #dept a
 group by a.name
```

and gotten

```
 salary 
 1800   
 500    
 1200
```

Now you can add a sub-query

```
select (select TOP(1) code from #dept_Codes b ) AS Code
,sum(salary) as salary
from #dept a
group by a.name
```

```
code    salary
XX  1800
XX  500
XX  1200
```

At this point the value of our sub-query is not bound to the row in any way. So its probably always going to give you the same value (Not guaranteed).

From this point you can link the tables based on name and get your query.

```
select (select TOP(1) code from #dept_Codes b where b.name = a.name ) AS Code
,sum(salary) as salary
from #dept a
group by a.name
```

Notice the TOP(1) that's important.

So do you have to add a second column to the "group by"? Maybe.

You could wright the statement below and it will run just fine, but if you want the actual value of a.id instead of the value through an aggregate function it will need to be part of the group by.

```
select (select TOP(1) code from #dept_Codes b where b.name = a.name and b.id = MIN(a.id) ) AS Code
,sum(salary) as salary
from #dept a
group by a.name
```

```
Code    salary
XX  1800
XXY 500
NULL    1200
```

Now as for your second question. If you look in the table above, you can see the last code is NULL. The sub-query evaluated to nothing so we got a NULL.
This is because code MAR only has an id of 5 in dept table, MIN(a.id) will be 3.